# Como chamar um atributo da classe em outra classe em django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Estou tentando criar umas classes que vão se relacionar de certa forma. A ideia é ser um jogo em que o player vai ter algumas opções de escolha e aí sua pontuação é baseada na pontuação das suas escolhas(meio que um fantasy game).

Por exemplo:

```
class PrimeiroConjunto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pontuacao = models.FloatField(max_length=4, null=False)

class SegundoConjunto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pontuacao = models.FloatField(max_length=4, null=False)

class TerceiroConjunto(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pontuacao = models.FloatField(max_length=4, null=False)

class Perfil(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    primeiraEscolha = models.ForeignKey(PrimeiroConjunto)
    segundaEscolha = models.ForeignKey(SegundoConjunto)
    terceiraEscolha = models.ForeignKey(TerceiroConjunto)
```

Então a classe Perfil teria uma relação com 3 outras classes (que possuem elementos diferentes entre si). E seria necessário acessar a pontuação de cada escolha.

Só que eu não sei como relacionar essas classes adicionando direto no banco, por exemplo, digamos que no PrimeiroConjunto eu tenha 3 elementos:

Pedro - 100 Pontos

Alvaro - 70 Pontos

Bruno - 150 Pontos

e agora eu queira adicionar um perfil no banco que vai a escolha do PrimeiroConjunto seria Alvaro por exemplo, como posso fazer isso?

Porque o único modo que eu conheço até agora de adicionar um item no banco é manualmente através do prompt de comando, por exemplo:

```
>>>from abc.models import Perfil
>>>perfil = Perfil(nome='Gabriel', ???)
>>>perfil.save()
```

Então, fazendo desse modo, o que eu colocaria no lugar das "???" para na associar o perfil de Gabriel com Alvaro da classe `PrimeiroConjunto`, para aí acessar sua pontuação,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode colocar a instância para o próprio objeto. Exemplo:

```
>>> from abc.models import Perfil, PrimeiroConjunto
>>> conjunto = PrimeiroConjunto.objects.get(nome='Alvaro')
>>> perfil = Perfil(nome='Gabriel', primeiraEscolha=conjunto)
>>> perfil.save()
```

Você também pode adicionar itens no banco usando as *views*, não precisa ser no *prompt*. Mas aí elas geralmente estarão associadas a formulários(*forms*). Você pode encontrar mais detalhes [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms).