# Qual a forma 'natural' de devolver uma instancia de classe como objeto de outra através de um construtor

Tags: php

Supondo que na situação X eu quero devolver um instancia de classe através de variáveis, não vejo problema em fazer isso:

```
$rs = "\\" .$Namespace . "\\" . $Class;
$inst = new $rs();
return $inst;
```

Em um exemplo, em que, eu queira ter a opção de usar um objeto de classe em outra classe pra modificar alguma coisa que não seria modificada por padrão, algo como uma coisa anormal, então eu teria isso:

```
class Dados{

   public function dado1(){
      return [1 => 'dado1',2 =>'dado2',3 =>'dado3'];
   }

   public function dado2(){
      return [4 => 'dado4',5=>'dado5',6 =>'dado6'];
   }

}    
class Componentes {

   public function junta($array1,$array2){
       return array_merge($array1,$array2);
   }

   public function transformaEmJson($array){
      return json_encode($array);
   }

}
class DevolverAsDuasClassesComOConstrutor {

    public $Componentes;
    public $Dados

    public function __construct() {

        $inst1 = new Dados();
        $this->Dados = $inst;
        $inst1 = new Componentes();
        $this->Componentes = $inst;
    }

}

$class = new DevolverAsDuasClassesComOConstrutor();

$dado1 = $class->Dados->dado1();
$dado2 = $class->Dados->dado2();
$arr = $class->Componentes->junta($dado1,$dado2);
$json = $class->Componentes->transformaEmJson($arr);
echo $json;
```

A ideia é usar uma classe sem métodos, pra devolver outras instancias, e usar essa classe com as instancias como uma classe extensível, já que ela vai conter as instancias do que estiver sendo feito.

No que eu to fazendo, esta funcionando certo, mas me parece estranho,quero saber se é uma boa ideia fazer isso (ter instancias como objeto) no ponto de vista de manutenção e desempenho do código?

No meu ponto de vista não parece ser uma boa prática, mas funcional, se eu estiver correto nisso (em não ser bom), como seria uma boa forma de obter o mesmo resultado ?

OBS: A Duvida é sobre ter a instancia de uma classe como objeto de outra.

Comment: O construtor do PHP não possui retorno, por padrão, então o `return` ali não tem efeito. Você já leu sobre o padrão de projeto *Factory*?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sei como funciona, mas não sei se é esse o contexto, acho que me expressei meio mal ali, mudei um pouco o enunciado, o Factory serviria pra substituir o modo como eu instancio a classe, mas eu to com duvida sobre manter a instancia como objeto, como no $this->inst = new algumaCoisa();

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, isso que você fez (a classe `DevolverInstancia`) parece uma espécie de indireção que pode inclusive simular o funcionamento de ponteiros de C em outras linguagens. Só no construtor dela que no caso você está fazendo uma introspecção que difere da estrutura "convencional" de uma indireção, que simplesmente armazenaria a instância. Sua dúvida para mim continua não clara

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado acho que agora ficou mais claro a pergunta

Comment: Ok, você quer um objeto complexo. Eventualmente você vai precisar acessar seus campos e resgatar os dados internos. Isso meio que vai contra o que entendo de encapsulamento, mas até aí nada de mais, perfeitamente plausível. Ter objetos dentro de objetos é desejável dentro de alguns contextos. Isso se chama de composição de objetos. Se a classe que encapsula a criação de objetos dentro de um contexto só serve para encapsular a criação, é basicamente um objeto anêmico. Tem diversos exemplos em outras linguagens, que usam classes/estereótipos/objetos.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sabe algum framework ou qlqr coisa em php ou python que use alguma coisa do tipo pra eu dar uma olhada ?

Comment: Serve Java não? Estou procurando aqui nas perguntas mais recentes mas não estou achando. Vou até procurar nas respostas do @AndersonCarlosWoss que lá tem muita coisa bacana

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado pode ser, vai ser um pouco mais difícil de entender mas ja ajuda, eu não sei o nome disso pra saber o que procurar

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, Django usa, acabei de lembrar. Quando você está descrevendo um modelo da base de dados, ele pede para que você descreva os diversos tipos de objeto do banco. Quando há uma relações com outras tabelas (sem ser relação many-to-many), você cria uma chave estrangeira apontando para a classe que descreve o outro objeto. Você pode pesquisar mais por [tag:django]; eu achei essa pergunta aqui que parece razoável para seu estudo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/272409/64969